# build.gradle line: 2 flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I get an error when running the application. I changed the system and installed all the programs again and the same error persists.

This error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\musta\AndroidStudioProjects\untitled\android\app\build.gradle' line: 2

* What went wrong:
Plugin [id: 'com.android.application'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (plugin dependency must include a version number for this source)

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

#### *[build.gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html)* file

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode =
    localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
    if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
        flutterVersionCode = '1'
    }

def flutterVersionName =
    localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
    if (flutterVersionName == null) {
        flutterVersionName = '1.0'
    }

android {
    namespace "com."
    compileSdkVersion 34
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

defaultConfig {
    // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID
    (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy { force 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0-alpha01' }
    }

    applicationId "com........................................"
    // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
    // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
    multiDexEnabled true
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release
    build.
        // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run
    --release` works.
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
 }
 packagingOptions {
    // Exclude file to avoid
    // Error: Duplicate files during packaging of APK
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    exclude 'META-
    INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
    exclude 'META-INF/*.kotlin_module'
      }
   }

   flutter {
        source '../..'
   }

   dependencies {}
```

Comment: Run flutter doctor -v and post it here.
Do you have any errors next to Android toolchain when you do?
If you do, re-install the Android SDK.
If flutter doctor says everything is ok, post your build.gradle here?

Comment: After Run flutter doctor -v  .. Everything is correct and there are no errors

Comment: Added
  build.gradle in answers
I have an old project that works without errors. About transferring the buildings to me
build.gradle in the new project but same errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

settings.gradle
add this code

```
plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin" version "1.0.0" apply false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add or update the **dependencies** in your **build.gradle** file in **app** folder.
or
You can add the zip url in **gradle-wrapper-properties** in **gradle/wrapper/** in **distributionUrl**

Answer (score -2):

It seems like there might be an issue with your Gradle setup or configuration. Here are a few steps you can try to troubleshoot and resolve this error:

1. **Check Gradle Plugin**: Ensure that your `build.gradle` file in the `android/app` directory specifies the correct Gradle plugin for Android application. It should look something like this:

   ```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
   ```
2. **Gradle Wrapper**: Verify that you have the Gradle wrapper files (`gradle-wrapper.properties`, `gradlew`, `gradlew.bat`) in your project directory. These files are essential for running Gradle tasks.
3. **Gradle Version**: Make sure that your project's `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` file specifies a valid Gradle version. You can set it to a specific version or use the default distribution provided by Android Studio.
4. **Check Gradle Plugin Repositories**: Ensure that your Gradle settings are configured to fetch plugins from the appropriate repositories. You can check your `settings.gradle` file and `build.gradle` files to ensure that the plugin dependencies are correctly specified.
5. **Clean and Rebuild**: Try cleaning your project and rebuilding it. You can do this from the Android Studio toolbar by selecting `Build > Clean Project` and then `Build > Rebuild Project`.
6. **Check Network Connection**: If you're behind a firewall or using a proxy, ensure that your network settings are configured correctly to allow Gradle to fetch dependencies from the internet.
7. **Update Gradle Plugin**: If you're using an older version of Android Studio or Gradle, consider updating to the latest version to see if the issue is resolved.
8. **Check Gradle Distribution URL**: In your `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` file, verify that the `distributionUrl` points to a valid Gradle distribution. It should look something like this:

   ```
   distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-x.x.x-all.zip
   ```

After trying these steps, attempt to rebuild your project again. If the issue persists, try running Gradle with the `--stacktrace`, `--info`, or `--debug` options as suggested in the error message to get more detailed information about the failure. Additionally, you can consult the provided link for more help or search for similar issues online to find potential solutions.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You should have already seen this in the banner while posting your answer, but please note that use of AI Tools (e.g., ChatGPT) to generate or reword content that you post [is not permitted](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831) on Stack Overflow, even if you've validated this content. Also see the related [Help](/help/ai-policy) on this topic. We do hope you'll stick around and become a valuable member of the community by contributing your own quality answers and questions in the future!